# How to manipulate hash keys to transform numeric months to names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an AR query that returns a hash of events per month, ordered by month

```
o.events.group("to_char(date,'MM')").order("to_char(date,'MM')").size()
```

I'm using numeric months in this query as it was the best way I could find to get things in the correct order, and I also need to do some other manipulations on the hash.

Before display the results, I need to convert the numeric months back to words. I added the following to the end of the query

```
.each_key{ |key| Date::MONTHNAMES[key] }
```

But i get

```
TypeError: can't convert String into Integer.
```

So i tried

```
.each_key{ |key| Date::MONTHNAMES[key.to_i] }
```

But the months remain in numeric form

```
{"01"=>4, "02"=>3.....
```

How can i manipulate this hash to get

```
{"January"=>4, "February"=>3.....
```

Comment: You shod tell us what you are actually trying to accomplish instead of telling us about the strange way you are trying to do it.  This is the "xy problem".

Comment: thanks david, i thought the question title and the final sentence pretty much summed up my requirements. Open to any suggestions you may have to improve. Feel free to edit my question

Answer (score 2):

Make a new Hash. If you can't, make a new key in the current hash and delete the original key. You can't simply change a key, since `key` is a local variable in the block, and changing it in no way impacts the contents of the Hash.

Answer (score 0):

This ? :

```
def number_to_month(number)
  (Time.now.beginning_of_year + number.months).strftime("%B")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to generate a new hash but I think you could just convert the strings to month names in your view right before displaying them.  Use the code you already wrote inside the block in your question but put it in your view.